# Как работать с числами с плавающей точкой не используя float double типы данных?

Tags: c

Например в стандартный поток ввести число(с плавающей точкой) +число(с плавающей точкой)  и вывести результат (число с плавающей точкой)  не используя float, double

Comment: например, используя числа с фиксированной точкой

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Операции сложения и вычитания тривиально переносятся на концептуальное *представление с фиксированной точкой*. То есть число `123.456` можно представлять как целое число `123456`, а число `789.123`, как число `789123`. Сумма этих чисел, с правильно поставленной точкой (три цифры справа), даст вам правильный ответ на вопрос о сумме исходных чисел `123.456` и `789.123`. Другими словами, все плавающие числа в таком подходе превращаются в целые через умножение на какой-то фиксированный множитель `M` (`1000` в моем примере) и последующее округление. При этом тривиальным образом сохраняется корректность операций сложения и вычитания.

Операция умножения для таких чисел также реализуется достаточно тривиально - надо выполнить целочисленное умножение и просто разделить его результат на множитель `M`. Операция деления реализуется путем предварительного умножения делителя на `M` и последующего выполнения целочисленного деления.

Схематично (Внимание: Чтение чисел через `scanf` будет работать неправильно на некоторых входах. Чтобы корректно прочитать дробную часть понадобится несколько более сложный код.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 1000

int main(void) 
{
  unsigned long long a, b, c, w, f;

  // Читаем `a`
  scanf("%llu.%3llu%*[0-9]", &w, &f);
  while (f >= M) f /= 10;
  a = w * M + f;

  // Читаем `b`
  scanf("%llu.%3llu%*[0-9]", &w, &f);
  while (f >= M) f /= 10;
  b = w * M + f;

  // Сложение - это обычное сложение
  c = a + b;

  // Выводим результат
  printf("%llu.%03llu + %llu.%03llu = %llu.%03llu\n", 
    a / M, a % M, b / M, b % M, c / M, c % M);

  // Умножение - это обычное умножение с пост-коррекцией
  c = a * b / M;

  // Выводим результат
  printf("%llu.%03llu * %llu.%03llu = %llu.%03llu\n", 
    a / M, a % M, b / M, b % M, c / M, c % M);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acbf006dde1e16b6

Comment: Не измененный был более понятен))

Comment: Чтобы выполнить эту операцию(вычисления)  массивы нужно использовать?

Comment: @King.c: Ым... Нет, никакой явной необходимости в массивах тут нет.

Comment: А как это реализовать?) никак не получается

Comment: У вас есть какая-то прога или что то похожее чтобы наглядно понять,  в чем состоит суть задачи

Comment: Хочу посмотреть, как AnT ответит на вопрос из последнего коммeнтария ).

Comment: @King.c: Понимание *сути* задачи - это уж ваша задача. Тут вам могут помочь найти *решение* задачи, но только после того, как вы нам изложите ее *суть*.