# Разделить целое число на константу с сохранением дробной части

Tags: c, float, embedded, int

Нужно разделить целое беззнаковое число, например 12, на константу 65535 и записать как **uint32**. При этом сохранить дробную часть. Тип **float** не поддерживается процессором. 
Какие есть варианты? Например до чего, я додумался - сдвинуть число на 16 позиций влево и разделить на 65535. Так вообще делается или есть другие способы?

Comment: Представление с фиксированной точкой. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897904/Как-работать-с-числами-с-плавающей-точкой-не-используя-float-double-типы-данных

Comment: Понятно, что с фиксированной точно, но тот ответ не дает ответ на мою задачу и даже не приближает.

Comment: А что дальше-то делать с этим числом с "сохранённой дробной частью"?

Comment: или фиксированная точка, или эмулировать плавающую точку (тулчейн обычно сам это умеет делать)... других вариантов ИМХО нет...

Comment: Можно поподробней про фиксированную точку, на моем примере.

Answer (score 0):

Д'елите, берёте остаток , и умножаете насколько надо.

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main  ( ) {
  uint32_t  a = 123456U  ;
  uint32_t  b = 789U ;
  printf  ("a = %u , b = %u\n",(unsigned int)a,(unsigned int)b);
  div_t r = div ( a , b ) ;
  printf  ("div = %u , rem = %u\n",(unsigned int)r.quot,(unsigned int)r.rem);
  printf  ("result = %u.%u\n",(unsigned int)r.quot,(unsigned int)((r.rem * 10) / b));
  }
```

;

```
> gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c99 divrem.c  
> ./a.out
a = 123456 , b = 789
div = 156 , rem = 372
result = 156.4
```

Comment: Нет, стандартную библиотеку не хочу использовать. Я полагаю, что надо 12 / 65535 представить как 12 * 1/65535. Тоесть представить дробь 1/65535 как число с фиксированной точкой. Вот как это сделать не понимаю до конца. 1/65535 = 0.000015259 = 0.00000000000000010000000000000000111001111110110110100000101111100001, а что делать дальше?

Comment: Циклом, `uint8_t arr[];while( пока не надоест){x=x<<8;arr[i]=x/d;x = x % d ;i=i+1;}`

Comment: Я не это имел ввиду. Есть десятичное число 0.000015259, которое в бинарном виде представляется как 0.0000000000000001000000000000000011100111. Так вот как зафиксировать точку и перемножить на 12?

Comment: @masb, а зачем вы вообще в 10 систему счисления переводите?! Объявите, что все ваши числа описываются с точностью до 2<sup>-16</sup>, да и все дела.