# Как объявить формат Q15 в си?

Tags: c

void compexp(float CT, float CS, float ET, float ES)

Вместо float нужно объявить формат Q15. И как потом вызвать этот формат? Помогите.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работать с форматом Q15? Как вообще тип данных float преобразовать в Q15. Можете привести пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024295/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-q15-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-float-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-q15-%d0%9c%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

В языке С нет встроенной поддержки форматов с фиксированной точкой.

Числа в формате с фиксированной точкой представляются на основе целочисленного типа подходящего размера. В вашем случае это может быть, например, `int32_t`.

А уж что касается реализации операций над числами, представленными в формате с фиксированной запятой, то они либо [реализуются вручную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897915/182825) (что тривиально для базовых арифметических операций), либо через постороннюю библиотеку.

Comment: Можете привести пример?