# Как работать с форматом Q15? Как вообще тип данных float преобразовать в Q15. Можете привести пример?

Tags: java, c++, c

Как вообще тип данных float преобразовать в Q15 в данном коде? Можете привести пример? Нужно вычислять что то, но не знаю как именно. Спасибо.

```
void compexp(short CT, short CS, short ET, short ES) {
//void compexp(0x7333, 0x7333, 0x7333, 0x7333) {
    float tav = 0.01;
    float at = 0.03;
    float rt = 0.003;
//  int delay = 150;
    int xrms = 0;
    int g = 1;

    DATA buffer[150] = {0};

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < W_LEN; ++i) {
        rin[i] = buf_in_right_1[i];
        lin[i] = buf_in_left_1[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < W_LEN; ++i) {
        xrms = (1 -tav) * xrms + tav * pow(rin[i], 2);
        float X = 10 * log(xrms);
        float G = min(0, CS * (CT - X), ES * (ET - X));
        int f = pow (10, G / 20);
        float coeff;

        if (f < g) {
            coeff = at;
        } else {
            coeff = rt;
        }

        g = (1 - coeff) * g + coeff * f;
        buf_out_right_1[i] = g * buffer[149];
        buf_out_left_1[i]  = g * buffer[149];

        buffer[0] = buf_in_left_1[i];
    }
  }


while (1) {

        if (effect_flag == EFFECT_FLAG) {
            compexp(1, 0.5, 1, -0.5);
            buf_out_left_1 = buf_in_left_1;
            buf_out_right_1 = buf_in_right_1;
            effect_flag = NO_EFFECT_FLAG;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, что я прочитал, должно быть как-то так:

```
int16_t ftoq15(float f)
{
  bool neg = f < 0;
  if (neg) f = -f;
  f = f * 32768 + .5;
  return (int)f | (neg ? 1 << 15 : 0);
}
```

Никаких тестовых данных ты не привёл, так что я ничего не проверял.

Comment: Весёлые результаты будут, если `f` лежит в интервале *(-1/32768,+1/32768)*.

Comment: @0andriy, ну так вроде оно и должно в этом интервале лежать? Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: С чего вы взяли? Полный интервал допустимых значений (-1, +1).

Comment: @0andriy, а стоп, перепутал с шагом. Ладно, для этого интервала будет одно из следующих чисел: 32769 (-1), 32768 (-0), +0 и +1. Что не так? Вроде соседний ответ почти то же самое делает?

Comment: Ну возьмите *f = -1.0 / 65537*. (Ну и рядом лежащие 65535, 65536). Поиграйтесь в общем, будут сюрпризы.

Comment: @0andriy, получается то, что я и ожидал: https://ideone.com/okG9SD. Что именно не так?

Comment: https://ideone.com/4nwRRa объяснять или всё понятно?

Comment: @0andriy, объяснять.

Comment: Ну так если у меня float = 0.01, то как происходит преобразование?

Comment: @FrankLampard, так это ты объяснить должен.

Answer (score 0):

[Q15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) значит, что это число с фиксированной точкой, с 15 битами после точки.

Чтобы из `float` сделать Q15, надо умножить его на 2<sup>15</sup> и округлить:

```
y = lround(x * 0x1p15f)
```

Обратное преобразование:

```
x = y / 0x1p15f
```

Comment: Почти как у меня, только ты с отрицательностью ничего не делаешь. Какого типа `y` и почему `lround`? Множитель [тот же](https://ideone.com/yx5YQo).

Comment: @Qwertiy Вроде с отрицательностью оно и так нормально работает. `y` - `short`, хотя с другими целыми типами тоже должно работать. `lround` - чтобы округлить и сразу преобразовать в целое.

Comment: как быть с tav = 0,01 ?

Comment: @FrankLampard Подставить в `lround(x * 0x1p15f)` и посчитать, или я вопрос не понял? Получится `328`.